# Android - Gradle sync failed: The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Okay so I made a bit of a shambles of moving my android-studio installation to another drive, so now when I try and go back to where I was, I can't even open a project any more as I get this error.

```
Gradle sync failed: The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
     Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings 
     or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Basically my C drive has only 1gb left in the SSD and realized earlier that Android is using up a huge amount of that, so I followed these steps to move everything to another drive. http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive

It was all going ok until the last part. Every time I started android studio it would create a new .androidStudio2.2 folder back in the C drive, which I don't know how to stop. Anyway I gave up and tried to go back to using the C drive with no disk space and this is where I'm at.

I've looked at a lot of solutions on here and nothing has worked.

Comment: if you go to gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties what is the distributionUrl ?

Answer (score 0):

you should edit your properties file,to change the path of gradle ,in your {AndroidStudio_Dir}/bin/idea.properties,edit it.remove the `#` of `idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio/config`,and other path you want to set.    And set the path in AndroidStudio `settings-->Build、Executing-->gradle:`,set Gradle home.

Comment: I've tried this, I set it like the following, but it still creates a new folder in the C drive. .... idea.config.path=D:/android/.AndroidStudio2.2/config
   idea.system.path=D:/android/.AndroidStudio2.2/system

Comment: modify : idea.config.path、idea.system.path、idea.plugins.path、idea.log.path，It isn't work??

Comment: I never actually changed the plug-ins or log path come to think of it. I'll do that in the morning and let you know how I get. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried this and still doesn't work. Even with all those paths set, Android still creates a new `.androidStudio2.2`folder in C drive. This is how my file looks now, `idea.config.path=D:/android/.AndroidStudio2.2/config
idea.system.path=D:/android/.AndroidStudio2.2/system
idea.plugins.path=D:/android/.AndroidStudio2.2/config/plugins
idea.log.path=D:/android/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/log`

Comment: I've decided to re-install android studio to fix this problem. I'm pointing it to my current SDK in the other drive and seems to working ok now.

Comment: I tried ,but it worked fine,you can delete the new created .androidstudio2.2， after you edit the idea.properties。

Comment: I'll try that. Even with a fresh install I'm having the same Gradle issue:(